# php - replacing all old <? tags to new ones <?php

Tags: php, regex

I have not much experience with php but i try to devise a simple way to convert old uncompactible php opening tag to 5.5 accepted version.

```
convert all <? opening tags to <?php
```

My application had more than 2000 php script and modules. I written this little peice of code to be able to call a recursive function to find and replace, using a regular expression all old tags to correct new ones. Theres seem to be a problem with my extension checking logic ( which seek to match only.php files).

Can someone point me out what i do wrong ? Or Is there a better solution to convert old php files to correct standard for php 5.5?

This is my little replacer.php file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
 <?php

function getItAll($dir) {

$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);

$i=0;

$fileNb = array();

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {

 $fileNb[$i] = $filename;

$i++;
```

Here i try to catch the file extension of the current browsed directory

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($fileNb[$i]);
$ext = $path_parts['extension'];

if($ext == '.php'){

$file = file_get_contents($fileNb[$i], true);
$pattern = '(?=[<]+[?][^<"?"phpa-zA-Z0-9+-.,!@#$%^&<*`?~();:\/\|>"_\\{\]\\[}])\D\W/g';

$replacement = "<?php";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $file);
echo "\n Replaced in: ($fileNb[$i]";
}
}
}
echo "\n";
echo "Replacing in $argv[1] directory \n";
getItAll($argv[1])
?>
```

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: Why not just enable short open tags on the server, or is that not an option?

Comment: surprise, its been asked before

Comment: The negated charclass `[^<"?"..]` is probably not what you want (albeit I have not idea what it's supposed to match or workaround exactly). You might wanna try [`phptags --long -v ./`](http://fossil.include-once.org/phptags/) instead (use --backup or --dry first).

Comment: @dagon Yes, it seem i missed the thread that seem to answer my question well ! Thank you all !

Comment: If your running linux then something here might lead you toward another solution: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files

Answer (score 0):

A way that uses the tokenizer:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -d short_open_tag=On
<?php
$source = file_get_contents('./tok_testfile.php');

foreach (token_get_all($source) as $token) {
    if (is_array($token))
        echo ($token[0] === T_OPEN_TAG) ? '<?php' : $token[1];
    else
        echo $token;
}
?>
```